# flask db query.all read one column of data

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to query my db and reassign one of the columns value to another value and pass the new value to the template for rendering. Should I be trying to accomplish this in flask or templating? And how can I accomplish this?

i have db model as:

```
class Items(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    item_type = db.Column(db.String(1), nullable=False)
```

i have flask function as:

```
@auth.route('/items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def list_items():
    items = Items.query.all()
    if items.item_type == "s":
      items.item_type = "Sod"
    return render_template('auth/item_list.html', items=items, title='Items')
```

i have template as:

```
<tbody>
{% for item in items %}                    
<tr>
 <td> {{ items.item_name }} </td>
 <td> {{ items.item_type }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over `items` to check the `item_type` of each `item`:

```
for item in items:
    if item.item_type == 's':
        item.item_type = "Sod"
```

And there are something wrong in your template file:

```
{% for item in items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.item_type }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly like I needed it to!